# Rails group count complex associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, count, associations, grouping

I want to group and count through my `has_one` association called `company_friend` this table has a column called `name`.

I'm using Rails 5.

```
class Appointment
  belongs_to :company_friendship, touch: true
  has_one :company_friend, through: :company_friendship
end

class CompanyFriendship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, touch: true
  belongs_to :company_friend, touch: true, class_name: "Company"
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_friendships, autosave: true
  has_many :company_friends, through: :company_friendships, autosave: true
end
```

I want to group using the `company_fiend.name` column

**The expected output should be like this:**

```
{"nestle" => 10, "cocacola" => 20, "los pollos hermanos" => 50}
```

I'm doing:

```
Appointment.joins(:company_friend).group("company_friends.name").count
```

But I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "company_friends"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, company_friends.name AS compan...
```

Comment: Can you show your `CompanyFriendship` and `CompanyFriend` models?

Comment: done, added the rest of the models @Gerry

Answer (score 3):

This is what I needed:

```
Appointment.joins(:company_friend).group("companies.name").count

{"Barton Mines"=>772, ... }
```